# How to create a specification for dates in JPA to find the greater/less etc?

Tags: spring, database, jpa

I have a Maria database with a table with a column named `registrated` what is a TIMESTAMP. I would like to make specifications to find records that are before/after a date. I have this:

```java
public class GreaterThanDate implements Specification<User> {
    
    private transient SearchCriteria criteria;
    
    public GreaterThanDate(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        criteria = searchCriteria;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
            return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get(criteria.getKey()), formatter.parse(criteria.getValue().toString()));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private Object value;
}
```

This is a date that is found in my database: `2020-09-01 08:00:00.000000`. If I try to find the records I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. This is how I call it:

```java
SearchCriteria criteria = new SearchCriteria("registered", "2020-09-01 08:00:00.000000");
GreaterThanDate specification = new GreaterThanDate(criteria);
userRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
```

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private ZonedDateTime registered;
}
```

> Exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid filter
> parameters.   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:289)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Also show us your User entity

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")`  the date format doesn't match with your input date `2020-09-01 08:00:00.000000`. You might be getting `ParseException`. Please try to match up your date format with expected date value. The rest looks good to me.

Comment: Added the User entity and stacktrace. If I change formatter to `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");` and pass the date I mentioned, it still does not work.

Comment: The stacktrace that you posted doesn't look like a full stacktrace

Comment: Also, the date format is still wrong. Run this `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
        Date d = formatter.parse("2020-09-01 08:00:00.000000");`

Comment: it's the same I wrote

Comment: Change this 
`} catch (ParseException e) { System.out.println(e.getMessage());}` to 

`} catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: Here you are burying the exception. There's definitely the ParseException going on. The stacktrace you posted is related to this but doesn't show the actual cause.. Because I think the actual problem is being buried

Comment: https://codeshare.io/ad3P4z here's a working example based on your setup. Not that I changed the date format to match with input. Also, since your entity uses ZonedDateTime, i'm passing the same type on your spec class

Comment: It's really working. Thank you. Create an answer so I can accept it and you can get some extra reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of problems with your code.

1. You entity class has `java.time.ZonedDateTime` type for the field. But you are trying to parse using `SimpleDateFormat` which is designed for old `java.util.Date`. Please use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse `ZonedDateTime`
   private ZonedDateTime registered;
2. The date format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` doesn't match with the input date `2020-09-01 08:00:00.000000` so you cannot use this format to parse the date. You will get ParseException
3. Do not bury the exception. The exception that you posted on question might have been raised due to a different error.

```
 } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

See this working example and do the similar to fix your problem:

```
package stackoverflowdatespec

import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryImplementation;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.criteria.*;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StackOverFlowDateSpecApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackOverFlowDateSpecApp.class, args);
    }
}

@Entity
@Data
@ToString
class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    private ZonedDateTime registered = ZonedDateTime.now();
}

interface ARepo extends JpaRepositoryImplementation<A, Long> {
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Init {
    final ARepo repo;
    @EventListener
    public void init(ContextRefreshedEvent evt) {
        repo.save(new A());
        System.out.println(repo.findAll());

        SearchCriteria criteria = new SearchCriteria("registered", "2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00");
        System.out.println(repo.findAll(new GreaterThanDate(criteria), Pageable.unpaged()).getContent());
    }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
class GreaterThanDate implements Specification<A> {
    private final SearchCriteria criteria;
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<A> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        ZonedDateTime before = ZonedDateTime.parse(criteria.getValue(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"));
        return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(criteria.getKey()), before);

    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String value;
}
```